# Script for "PID" linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, powershell, shell

I'm new here!

I have some processes running on the machine and sometimes when the process reaches its limit, it stops and immediately creates the same process with another PID.
For example, there is a java process running and when that java process stops, it creates a new java process instead of restoring / restoring the process that was stopped. From there, there is a pile of running java processes.

I wonder if there is any script that when a PID process ends, it can automatically restart.

[In the photo, when executing the command "top" we see that there are 3 processes (same thing) with the name "java"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1l8VM.png)

Comment: How did you get powershell on a Linux machine? I thought this is just Windows technology?

Comment: @Dominique: A new, cross-platform PowerShell edition was introduced in 2016 - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell#PowerShell_Core_6

Comment: Please clarify, by directly updating your question: you want to monitor a process with a given PID and restart the same command when the process terminates? How do you get the target PID to begin with? How do you know what command to relaunch?